# How to parse information from blog to iphone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, json, ios4

could someone point me in the right direction in how i can parse data from a blog to an iphone. E.g. You have a table view displaying the posts of the blog, you select a table cell and text content is displayed. Are there any tutorials/examples on this?

I have a bit of experience with parsing data using JSON (parsed data from database to iphone) but unsure on where to start with this?

Thanks for an help..

Comment: We need a lot more information to start with. =)  To parse XML you can use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Other than that more information is needed.

Comment: Its a simple wordpress blog, the blog has posts. Each post has a title and content. How can i access and parse each post onto the iphone?.

Comment: Do you have an RSS feed or some access by which you can access your site's posts in an XML format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is use the [Wordpress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/). The flow goes like this:

- Make an API call. This is a subject unto itself, but typically you'd use NSHTTPRequest and NSURLConnection to make the request.
- Parse the result. I forget if you get XML back; you probably do; in that case there are tons of solutions for parsing, including NSXMLParser and libxml2.
- Populate UITables, etc. with the retrieved information.

The Wordpress API is not that big or complex, but it's a bigger subject than I can really get into in the context of an SO answer, so I'll just refer you to the aforelinked documentation and wish you happy reading.